# Net Core 2.0 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config) is not thread safe

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, autofac

Platform: NetCore 2.0

Issue location: getting `IOptionsSnapshot` in service constructor.

Description: Under loading testing with high pressure I had an exception (very rarely):  "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." 
It happens in class\function `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config)`  line 269

`if(config != null && config.GetChildren().Any())`

Regarding trace log it happens in linq function `Any()`. Looks like `ConfigurationBinder` is not thread safe here.

Any thoughts how it could be fixed?

Trace logs:

```
[2017-12-22T09:37:38.3955213Z] Level=Error, Category=Autofac, Id=qq, 
Message= Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = PlaybackService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.IPlaybackService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IntegrationService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.IIntegrationService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TokenRepository (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ITokenRepository], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.DXXXXConfig], XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ICertificateRepository)' on type 'TokenRepository'. --->
 Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (See inner exception for details.) --->
 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IntegrationService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.IIntegrationService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TokenRepository (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ITokenRepository], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.DXXXXXXConfig], XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ICertificateRepository)' on type 'TokenRepository'. --->
 Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) --->
 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TokenRepository (ReflectionActivator), Services = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ITokenRepository], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope --->
 An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.DXXXXConfig], XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ICertificateRepository)' on type 'TokenRepository'. --->
 Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) --->
 Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.DXXXXConfig], XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.ICertificateRepository)' on type 'TokenRepository'. --->
 Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. (See inner exception for details.) --->
 System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion()
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.ReserveOrAdd(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat2Iterator`1.ToArray()
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d_3.MoveNext()
  at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.ReserveOrAdd(IEnumerable`1 items)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat2Iterator`1.ToArray()
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d3.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator`1.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindProperty(PropertyInfo property, Object instance, IConfiguration config)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindNonScalar(IConfiguration configuration, Object instance)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, Object instance, IConfiguration config)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Bind(IConfiguration configuration, Object instance)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
  at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
  at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
  at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() — End of inner exception stack trace —
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) — End of inner exception stack trace —
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) — End of inner exception stack trace —
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
  at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) — End of inner exception stack trace —
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
  at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>cDisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>gCreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d_14.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---... MESSAGE Truncated=True DUE TO EXCEEDING MaxAllowedCharacterLength=10000, ActualCharacterLength=11707
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Before going furthe, please take the time to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Create Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm seeing something similar in my application.  There could be an incompatibility with Autofac's AspNetCore DI adapter.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue using the net core 2.2 and default DI container. Under load testing, app crashes randomly with the same error. haven't found any solution yet.